# Composing a custom binary packet in C++ efficiently

Tags: c++

I need to stream over TCP a packet that looks like this:

```
Unsigned Long A  + Byte B[32] + Unsigned Long C
```

A and C are numbers, B is an array of bytes containing a sha256 hash. On the server side knowing the structure of the packet I can parse it like first 4 bytes is A next 32 is the hash an so... In my client, wrote in C++ I'm having problems to write the code in a cleaner way:

```
String hn_token = readToken();
long nounce = getNounce();
String secret = String(hn_token) + "{" + String(nounce) +  "}";
char buff[128] = {};
int len = secret.length()+1;
secret.toCharArray(buff, len);
String secretHash  = sha256(buff, len-1);
char stream[64] = {};
secretHash.toCharArray(stream, 64);
client.write((const uint8_t*)stream, 64);
```

That part is only the generation and delivery of B, but already looks bad going from String to Char array to String again and so. Is there a way to compose the packet in a more elegant and efficient way?

Comment: What is `String`? Perhaps you meant `std::string`. Where is `readToken` defined

Comment: Relying on the size of datatypes is not at all portable. Use stdint.h typedefs to get the sizes you want. For instance, use uint32_t for a 4 byte value.